# Select COUNT for each value

Tags: mysql, html-table

My table looks like this:

```
id    type    value
1    type1    Good
2    type1    Bad
3    type1    Match
4    type2    Good
5    type2    Bad
6    type2    Match
7    type3    Good
8    type3    Bad
9    type3    Match
```

each 'type' have 3 possible value options

Currently I use this code to preview data

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT type, value, COUNT(*) FROM data GROUP BY type,value ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC"); 
echo "<table border='1'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
echo "<tr>";
echo '<td><FONT SIZE=3 COLOR=BLACK> ' . $row['type'] .  '  </FONT></td>';
echo '<td><FONT SIZE=3 COLOR=BLACK> ' . $row['value'] .  '  </FONT></td>';
echo '<td><FONT SIZE=4 COLOR=GREEN> ' .$row['COUNT(*)'] . '</FONT></td>';}  
echo "<tr>";  
echo "</table>";
```

So, results from table its displayed in 3 column with many rows(3*3*3)

I am trying to display it in a table with 4 column and only 3 row
like this one:

```
type    COUNT "Good"    COUNT "Bad" COUNT "Match"
type1       1               1             1
type2       1               1             1
type3       1               1             1
```

and I am not sure how to do that.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can (ab)use a combination of `SUM` with `CASE` to do this:

```
SELECT type,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type='Good' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS good,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type='Bad' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bad,
       SUM(CASE WHEN type='Match' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS match
  FROM data
  GROUP BY type
```

This will group all values based on the type, then use `SUM` to find out how many of each values there are. By using `CASE` we either sum up zeroes or ones for each row, so it only adds up to one of the "counts."

Answer (score 1):

You can use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT type, 
       SUM(value='Good') AS Good,
       SUM(value='Bad') AS Bad,
       SUM(value='Match') AS Match,
FROM mytable
GROUP BY type
```

Comment: perfect
exact what i need

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an alternative using `count` since this is more understandable of what it does.

From the [w3schools doc](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp), we can see that the `count` doesn't take the null value

> The COUNT(column_name) function returns the number of values (NULL values will not be counted)

So by removing the else value it will count only the rows that match the case statement. (any non-null values can be used instead of `1`)

This is validated in the comments in the [MySQL count()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html)

```
SELECT type,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type='Good'  THEN 1 END) AS good,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type='Bad'   THEN 1 END) AS bad,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN type='Match' THEN 1 END) AS match
  FROM data
  GROUP BY type
```

*The following works in Sybase, if someone find out this doesn't work on mysql, please notify me because I don't have a mysql ready to test.*